# Rails 3: Scope on an optional has_one association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, scope, arel

I have two models: Sale and Payment

```
class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :payment
end

class SaleCancelation < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :payment
end
```

I want to create two scopes, "with payment" and "without payment".

"with_payment" works easyly:

```
class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
  scope :with_payment, joins( :payment )
end
```

But how can I create a scope that finds every sale that does **not** have an associated Payment?

Comment: (Cannot answer own question for 8 hours, so solution goes here).

Just found the solution, using the MetaWhere Gem (detailed explenation here: http://metautonomo.us/2010/11/02/metawhere-is-about-to-get-func-y/

`scope :without_payment, joins(:payment.outer).where(:payment => {:id => nil})`

(Notice the **:payment.outer**, which creates an outer join instead of an inner join, which makes all the difference in this case.)

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```
scope :without_payment, where( 'id not in (select sales_id from payments)' )
```

Comment: Found another way, still deciding which one I'll keep :D, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Another way to do it:

```
scope :without_profile, lambda { includes(:user_profile).where('user_profiles.id is null') }
```

Comment: I prefer this solution because the join will be faster than the subquery.